# How can I close the turtle screen in python but make it still working in the background?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to make distance calculator and I am using turtle, so I don't want to show the screen, I just want to get the position of the turtle without opening the screen.

Neither do `turtle.exitonclick()` nor `turtle.bye` aka `turtle.Screen().bye`

So what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I would suggest would be hiding your turtle at turtle setup and set its speed to max;

```
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(0)
```

At the end of your script you can put below method so screen closes;

```
turtle.bye()
```

Since turtle needs to move on screen in order for you to get its location. But with above approac there wont be any visible animation running on screen.

We can help more if you send your script as well when asking questions.